# using SSE with nginx server on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: nginx, server-sent-events

I am using asp.net core with SSE (Server Sent Events).

I can run it all well on my local PC.

i have deployed it to my raspberry pi and I have used nginx to serve this web server to the rest of my network.  But it does not work.  I have put logging so and no errors. The server code thinks it has been sent. However, my JS client does not receive the message.  I suspect that I need to use a domain name registered to my Rpi?

I hope I am wrong and that it can be solved in my nginx configuration.

I can post all my code but if the above is true then it could never work.

Any advice or code requests?

ADDITONAL:

My default config file:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
 default upgrade;     
}

server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;
}

server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;
 #listen               443;
 ssl                  on;
 ssl_certificate      /home/pi/web/localhost.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key  /home/pi/web/localhost.key;
 ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
 # ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

 root /var/www/html;

 server_name _;

 location /web/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  http;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path   /FindMotion;
  }
}
```

(I am not sure what to put in the upstream.  It can only be localhost, 127.0.0.1?)

[image]

Comment: "The server code thinks it has been sent."  What exactly do you mean by that?  "I suspect that I need to use a domain name registered to my Rpi?"  No, that doesn't sound relevant.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for commenting.  The last part of you comment is encouraging to me. The 1st part is: I put logging around the last line of server code that sends the message to the client,  No errors. So I am assuming the client and server cannot find each other? I can post code and nginx default if required

Comment: Narrow this problem down... is it an issue between the client and Nginx?  Your application and Nginx?

Comment: @brad I know this is a weak answer but i do not know. Apart from asp.net this i sall new to me.  I had origainally tried to use websockets. But, unless I could provide a SSL that points to a genuine/registered domain name it wil not work. So I  am taking a look at SSE. As I am receiving no errors in asp.net core, logging in messages, nginx, syslog I have not got a clue

Comment: Not sure what your HTTPS certificate has to do with your choice between Web Sockets and SSE.  The same restrictions apply to both.  In any case, first, make sure your logging is working in Nginx.  You can do this by causing an error and ensuring it's showing up in your logs.  Once you know your logging is working, make an HTTP request to your upstream ASP.NET server from the same host Nginx is on, and verify that's working.  (Use cURL or something.)  If that's working, then on the client, make your HTTP request to Nginx and figure out what the actual response data is.  Use Fiddler or similar.

Comment: Also, if you're not using HTTPS, you can simply use Wireshark/tcpdump to look at the raw data on the wire and narrow the problem down.

Comment: @Brad My webocket will work if I point the upstream to my domain registered server. If I point it to the DHCP assigned to the Rpi it will not.  Connection Refused.  The 'ws' part of the uri is automatically changed by nginx to 'wss' so I have to use SSL. The SSL on my domain server works for all of this but if I try to run the same from my Rpi it will not. The only differences are I am hosting on a dhcp address and I am using Open SSL

Comment: @I have to use SSL.. as that is the way the web is going,

Comment: Can you put a diagram in your question, label everything with the addresses and what not, with your Nginx upstream config?

Comment: @brad sure.. I shall put my nginx config up now (and willl remove the  websocket stuff for  clarity and then work on that diagram)

Comment: @brad "HTTP request to your upstream ASP.NET server from the same host Nginx i" I can make a REST Api client cal from JavaScript client to ASP.NET controller . It all works.

Comment: @Brad Just run Fiddler. Apart from the inital view being loaded I can see no connection between server and my client.

Comment: It doesn't sound like your client is attempting to make a request then, so this problem is likely client-side.  Any errors on your JavaScript console?  Can you show a relevant code snippet where you make the SSE connection?